# Angular 4 - Unit testing using Jasmine - Button click code showing error

Tags: html, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am new to Jasmine. Writing code in Angular 4. I want to test a button. I wrote following code in my spec file. This is the functionality of multi file upload. And on selection of file(s), we are allowing user to upload files.

```
import {
    async,
    ComponentFixture,
    TestBed
} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {
    UploaddocumentComponent
} from './uploaddocument.component';

describe('UploaddocumentComponent', () => {
    let component: UploaddocumentComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture < UploaddocumentComponent > ;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [UploaddocumentComponent]
            })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UploaddocumentComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    // it('should create', () => {
    //   expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    // });
    it('should', async(() => {
        spyOn(component, 'uploadFileByRest');

        let button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
        button.click();

        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            expect(component.uploadFileByRest).toHaveBeenCalled();
        })
    }));
});
```

In PhantomJS browser, seeing following issue. How to resolve?

```
invoke@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:490:0 <- src/polyfills.ts:3454:
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.981 
secs/ 0.127 secs)
```

`HTML`

```
<button pButton type="button" icon="fa-check" class="form-control" 
(click)="uploadFileByRest(); file.value = ''" [disabled]="!isFileSelected"
label="Upload"></button>
```

`TS`

```
doUploadByRest() {
   //Saving file to Alfresco and DB
}
```

Chrome showing as

[image]

HTML 21 line it's showing issue I think, isRequestFromView - how to give input to testing code?

```
    21 line <div class="row" *ngIf="!isRequestFromView">
        <p-messages [(value)]="msgs"></p-messages>            
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>Add File:</label>
            <input multiple type="file" name="filedata" class="form-control" #file (change)="fileChangeEvent(file.files)" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"  style="margin-top:25px">
            <button pButton type="button" icon="fa-check" class="form-control" (click)="uploadFile(); file.value = ''" [disabled]="!isFileSelected"
                label="Upload"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you share the component's html/ts? Also, can you try to run it in chrome, it might have a more detailed error message.

Comment: I updated HTML and TS code. I am not able to run in chrome. I add in karma.conf.js - browsers: [ 'Chrome']. Coming some error for that 
11 07 2017 20:20:38.012:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot load browser "Chrome": it is not registered! Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
11 07 2017 20:20:38.012:ERROR [karma]: Found 1 load error

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the PrimeNG component `Messages` to your declarations:

```
import {Messages} from "primeng/primeng";

...

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [UploaddocumentComponent, Message]
        })
        .compileComponents();
}));
```

This is because Jasmine tests don't automatically import your dependencies. This gives you more control over your test environement, allowing you to mock components as needed.

If this gives you further errors, try mocking the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'p-messages',
  template: ''
})
class MyMessageMock {

}

...

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [UploaddocumentComponent, MyMessageMock]
        })
        .compileComponents();
}));
```

This will leave you with an empty component where your `<p-messages>` element was, which should not impact your test since you're testing something else entirely.