# An error was thrown in afterAll when running Angular UT

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

When running my UT with Karma I get

> An error was thrown in afterAll
> TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, ReadableStream, Array, AsyncIterable, or Iterable.
> at createInvalidObservableTypeError (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/util/throwUnobservableError.js:2:1)
> at innerFrom (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/observable/innerFrom.js:37:43)
> at doInnerSub (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/operators/mergeInternals.js:19:18)
> at outerNext (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/operators/mergeInternals.js:14:1)
> at OperatorSubscriber._next (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/operators/OperatorSubscriber.js:13:1)
> at OperatorSubscriber.next (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/Subscriber.js:31:1)
> at Observable._subscribe (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/observable/innerFrom.js:51:24)
> at Observable._trySubscribe (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/Observable.js:37:1)
> at http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/Observable.js:31:1
> at errorContext (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/util/errorContext.js:19:1)

Is there a way to identify from where is this error coming from? I cannot find which UT file is causing this error

Comment: Hello, obviously you provide very little detail to help. You probably should deactivate all your tests to sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Alain's point, do you know which test throws that error? If it is always the same test, good chance that it is that test that is causing the error.

If you don't know which test is causing the error, you can write `xdescribe` instead of `describe` for all tests and this will cause the tests to be skipped. Then remove one `x` at a time and it should hopefully give you a hint in to which unit test file is the problematic one. You can even do `xit` instead of `it` to skip individual tests as well.

Comment: I have more than 254 UT now running, but this error is random, sometime it happens sometimes it doesn't. the question is: is there a way to figure out which Test is throwing this error? or I will just have to disable them all and test 1 by 1 ?

Comment: You should see which test threw that error most likely, check out the imagine in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45037537/7365461. `Uploaddocument: should` is the test that is causing the error. If you don't have that, then yes, unfortunately you will have to do it one by one.